# displaying unix timestamp-time not matching to server time

Tags: php

I have used in PHP to print the current date and time:

```
              $now = time();
              echo date('j M, Y H:i:s',$now);
```

The result is accurate as far as date,month,year is concerned. But the time is not matching on the same computer(as am testing in localhost).PHP script shows: 9 Nov, 2013 02:35:11 whereas the time on my pc is: 8:05 AM

Comment: Take a look here http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/dates-and-time-the-oop-way/ and learn how to work with timezones...

Comment: It implies that it is a time-zone problem,right? thanks @HenriqueBarcelos

Comment: Yes... And you don't need to rely only on the global timezone difined in the server, you can work with any timezone you want with class [`DateTimeZone`](http://br.php.net/datetimezone)

Comment: thanx @HenriqueBarcelos as I am new in "time" computing, so words of advice are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways of working with timezones:

1. Setting a default timezone in your php.ini file (NOT recommended):

   ```
   [Date]
   ; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
   ; http://php.net/date.timezone
   date.timezone = America/Sao_Paulo
   ```

   This will work for just PHP files running on the server that is configured by this php.ini.
2. Setting a default timezone in you initialization PHP script:

   [date_deafult_timezone_set](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)

   ```
   date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
   ```

   This will work for almost all scripts.
3. Working with a DateTimeZone object:

   ```
   $date = new DateTime('2013-11-09 01:08:32', new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));
   ```

   This will work for all scripts, but can get a little bit tedious.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your php.ini is using a different timezone.

Comment: o' ... really... but how do I change this ?

Comment: you can either use @HenriqueBarcelos solution (setting the timezone just for that script) or change the php.ini time zone, so all scripts will use that timezone (unless you specify one).

Locate your php.ini file (I don't know what platform you are using) and look for a line like this one

    date.timezone = America/New_York

and use the desired timezone, [here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) is a list of the timezones you can use

Comment: @GuillemoMansilla: There might well be several php.ini files. My box has one for command line, one for GUI, and one for CGI.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be use to you (change to your timezone of course):

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/Phoenix");
```

Conversion function:

```
// converts from UTC to Phoenix time
function timezone_convert($datetime) {
    $datetime = new DateTime($datetime);
    $phx_time = new DateTimeZone('America/Phoenix');
    $datetime->setTimezone($phx_time);
    $datetime = $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');   
    return $datetime;
}
```

Comment: But if you set your defaut timezone to a value, there is no reason to "convert" to the same timezone...

Comment: Both should not be read in same context. Two different things (example code).